# Making box-plot with only particular rows pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, data-analysis

So, I have data looking like this. This is a very small set of how my dataset looks.

```
   VehicleID    FinancialYear   Type                Make    ConditionScore
        119        2000-01     Personnel Vehicle    Ford            55
        124        2000-01    Heavy Goods Vehicle   MAN             10
        174        2000-01    Light Goods Vehicle   Ford            20
        400        2002-03    Light Goods Vehicle   Volkswagen      65
        475        2002-03    Personnel Vehicle      Ford          100
        774        2003-03    Light Goods Vehicle    MAN            35
        845        2006-07     Personnel Vehicle     Ford           60
        847        2006-07    Heavy Goods Vehicle   Ford            50
        956        2006-07  Light Goods Vehicle Iveco               10
```

I am trying to create a boxplot of the particular years (so like, boxplot of just the values of 2000-01 and then just values of 2006-07) but since I'm a little new to pandas python struggling a bit. Could anyone suggest ways to do the above?

Comment: A box-plot is a plot of a distribution of values, not of a single one: what is it exactly that you want to do (as you only have one additional column and not a data set in correspondence of each year)?

Comment: @gented My dataset is much larger than the above. That is just an example of how my dataset looks. I am trying to find outliers in the specific years. I have about 1000 values of each year and I am trying to find if there is an outlier in any year. I feel box plot would be useful to do this.

Comment: @gented Updated my description. Hope it makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create small dummy data set, import your real data here instead
data = pd.DataFrame([['2009-10', 89], ['2009-10', 60], ['2010-11', 85]],
                    columns=['Year', 'Score'])

plt.figure()
data[data['Year'] == '2009-10'].boxplot(column='Score')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: It says list of out range. I have updated the way my dataset looks

Comment: I have just edited my answer to reflect the new column names in your updated post. Does it work now?

Comment: It says list out of range.

Comment: Can you check the data type of your 'ConditionScore' column? I think it could be causing the issue - it needs to be a numeric type. You can check this by printing `data.dtypes`.

Comment: I used "print(is_numeric_dtype(dfs['ConditionScore']))" and it says true. I tried printing data[data['FinancialYear'] == '2009-10'] and it showed me all 30k columns  with True where its '2009-10'. EDIT: When I do data.dtypes(), it says "'Series' object is not callable"

Comment: `data.dtypes` is an attribute rather than a method, so no () needed.

Comment: Ah. It says int64. EDIT: So, I just ran the code you originally said above again. Now weirdly, it doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't show the box plot. I am so confused.

Comment: Does it work for you if you try it on some tiny dummy dataset rather than on your real data? Here's the tiny example I used that worked correctly: `data = pd.DataFrame([['2009-10', 89], ['2009-10', 60], ['2010-11', 85]], columns=['Year', 'Score'])`

Comment: data[data['Year'] == '2009-10'].boxplot(column='Score'). This is the code I tried to create the box plot with your dataset. It does the same for me. A python symbol pops up on my Dock at the bottom and then disappears without showing the box plot

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a few extra lines which should save your plot to file in your current working directory. Does this work?

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. It finally works. Not sure why it doesn't show but it saves which is also fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted! `plt.show()` might work for you, but I can't confirm for sure as it just shows automatically for me in my environment anyway without having to explicitly state it.